# Translating from Hebrew into English

Tags: translation

How do you translate the following Hebrew words into English?
"Ba’al Simchah"

Answer (score 3):

Literally means "master of the joy". In other words, he is the "owner" of the joyful event such as a wedding / Bar Mitzvah, etc. or, in short, the "host".